# how do I convert a cookie into a variable in php?

Tags: php, cookies

Let's say the user logs in, a cookie is sent and the user is redirected to another page.

How do I make it where I can convert the cookie value into a variable in PHP (on the page they are redirected to)?

I want to write the cookie value to a .txt file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php):

> Any cookies sent to you from the client will automatically be included into a `$_COOKIE` auto-global array if `variables_order` contains "C".

Answer (score 3):

Well cookies live in the [`$_COOKIE`](http://php.net/_COOKIE) global. (When received.)

And writing them to a file would be as boring as:

```
 file_put_contents("var/cookie.txt", $_COOKIE["cookiename"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert them just retrieve into a php variable.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['lastVisit']))
    $visit = $_COOKIE['lastVisit']; 
else
    echo "You've got some stale cookies!";

echo "Your last visit was - ". $visit;
?>
```

see here [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Cookies stored in the `$_COOKIE` array. So if you want to use it, just assign an appropriate cookie key value to your variable, for example:

```
$name = $_COOKIE['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be accessed in the global `$_COOKIE` array.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is available in `$_COOKIE` as `$_COOKIE['key']`; get that value and store it in a variable, which can be output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`$newvar = $_COOKIE['cookiename'];`